# Implementing Objective-C methods into Swift program

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm just getting started on an app that should eventually run a DIY CNC machine via an Arduino UNO. I've found a few resources for serial communication written in Objective-C so I figured I'd try to make it work. I'm trying to implement a function that will search for available serial ports on the computer and present them in a drop-down menu.

Xcode isn't complaining about any of the Objective-C components so I'm going to assume that's not the problem right now. However, Xcode gives me the error: "Use of unresolved identifier 'refreshSerialList'". This is the manner suggested by Apple to call an Objective-C method in Swift: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Serial.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

// import IOKit headers
#include <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>
#include <IOKit/serial/IOSerialKeys.h>
#include <IOKit/IOBSD.h>
#include <IOKit/serial/ioss.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

@interface Serial : NSObject {
IBOutlet NSPopUpButton *serialListPullDown;
}

- (void) refreshSerialList: (NSString *) selectedText;

@end
```

Serial.m

```
#import "Serial.h"

@implementation Serial

- (void) refreshSerialList: (NSString *) selectedText {
    io_object_t serialPort;
    io_iterator_t serialPortIterator;

    // remove everything from the pull down list
    [serialListPullDown removeAllItems];

    // ask for all the serial ports
    IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault,     IOServiceMatching(kIOSerialBSDServiceValue), &serialPortIterator);

    // loop through all the serial ports and add them to the array
    while (serialPort == IOIteratorNext(serialPortIterator)) {
        [serialListPullDown addItemWithTitle:
         (__bridge NSString*)IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(serialPort,     CFSTR(kIOCalloutDeviceKey),  kCFAllocatorDefault, 0)];
        IOObjectRelease(serialPort);
    }

    // add the selected text to the top
    [serialListPullDown insertItemWithTitle:selectedText atIndex:0];
    [serialListPullDown selectItemAtIndex:0];

    IOObjectRelease(serialPortIterator);
}

@end
```

Bridging Header.h

```
#import "Serial.h"
```

AppDelegate.Swift

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var window: NSWindow!

    @IBOutlet var CommandInput : NSView!

    @IBOutlet var serialListPullDown : NSPopUpButton!


    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application

        let refresh = refreshSerialList()

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    @IBAction func CommandSend(sender : AnyObject) {
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you need to create a Serial object first to call the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`refreshSerialList` takes one parameter, a string. So first you'd have to create an instance of Serial:

```
var serial = Serial()
```

then call the method on the instance:

```
serial.refreshSerialList("some string")
```

Answer (score 0):

`while (serialPort == IOIteratorNext(serialPortIterator))`

tests the value of serialPort against each value of IOIteratorNext(serialPortIterator). But serialPort never gets assigned a value so this will not work. What's required is:

```
while (serialPort = IOIteratorNext(serialPortIterator))
```

which both assigns a value to serialPort and tests its value.

In Swift, an assignment in an if clause is not allowed. In Swift, what's required is:

```
repeat {
    serialPort = IOIteratorNext(serialPortIterator)
    if (serialPort != 0) {
        <statement>
        <statement>
    }
} while serialPort != 0
```